# CORS giving same policy error in VUE webapp with LUMEN API

Tags: vue.js, web-applications, lumen

I am working on Vue.js Webapp with backend as Lumen API.

At first, I got CORS error for which i added 
** CORS middleware **
and 
 **Disabled the web-security**

It worked fine for developement.
But in production

I get error:

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://doorstepapi.000webhostapp.com/api/item/BJE-00. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).

In **CORS middleware**

```
$headers = [
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'      => 'https://whyiexist.github.io',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods'     => 'GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' => 'true',
            'Access-Control-Max-Age'           => '86400',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers'     => 'Content-Type,X-api-token,X-Requested-With',
            //'Access-Control-Expose-Headers'     => 'X-api-token'
        ];
```

Can someone help how to solve this error

Comment: Is your frontend running at https://whyiexist.github.io ?

Comment: yes, exactly.. It's a VueJs app